# CDK AWS Is it possible to grant a role access to a specific method or is it only possible to grant for the whole API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have the following

```
let lambdaFunction = <some lambda construct here> 
lambdaFunction.grantInvoke(props.invocationRole);
```

And that grants hydra the ability to invoke that lambda, but what if I had an api endpoint method?

```
let endpoint = resource.addMethod(method['method'], lambdaIntegration, {
                    authorizationType: AuthorizationType.IAM,
                    requestValidator: props.requestValidator,
                    requestModels: {'application/json': props.validationModel}
                })
```

Is it possible to grant the role that I have access to just this endpoint access or do I have to do it on the api gateway resource level?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with API Gateway, however it looks like it does support access control using the specificity of a particular endpoint.

Reference Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html

Using the CDK, you can apply a policy with the same structure as the examples in the docs.